Where is the first pin when a chip has a bar and not a dot
this chip has a bar as an indicator,
could you please tell how to locate 1st pin


Who makes it? What do they say on the data sheet?

Tpic6c595, in datasheet it's a dot, not bar

The top left in the provided photo. If you know what chip that is (some '595 made by TI) you can verify from the data sheet.

Top left referred to what?

@MrGerber You can assume referred to the photo of the chip provided in the question.

@Justme Assumptions aren't a great way to answer questions explicitly asking for positional information.

@tashus which other reference could it possibly be?

@Stian it's not unreasonable to think that top left means top left in reference to holding the chip so the text on the chip has the correct orientation, so top right in the photo.

@Ivo That is precisely what I would have expected.

I've circled it for you:

But always take a look at the datasheet, too. Start with identifying the package as D:

Then go look at the package:

The bar (perhaps memorable as an I) identifies the index area.

It's perhaps a bit high-handed to assert that that drawing from the datasheet clearly identifies the interpretation of markings which aren't even present in the drawing. Yes, pin 1 is pin 1. But there's no "index area" on the chip where that arrow is pointing.

@Sneftel Only thought it might help some. And that line does indicate the index.

I do not see the bar in the datasheet picture...

The bar, notch or other marking indicates the pin 1/pin 16 end of the chip, and the pins are numbered counter-clockwise from that end. This applies to all DIP packages, and to many other packages.
When you hold the IC as in your photo, pin 1 will be the top left pin.
Edit: On DIP and DIP-like packages, if you hold the part so the writing is right way up, pin 1 will be at the bottom left corner.

If you turn the IC so that the bar is on the left, the pin number 1 is BOTTOM LEFT.


As per the package drawing in periblepsis's  answer, the indicator on this package is a chamfer running all the way down one of the long sides (on the left in your original photo). The chamfer is clearly visible on the photo in Edin Fifić's answer.
